# Twitter Data Archive

Tags: twitter

is there any service from where we can download tweets?

**UPDATE!!!**
Googling for sometime gave me this result
a.) http://snap.stanford.edu/data/twitter7.html
b.) http://140kit.com/datasets

Comment: this link doesn't work:  http://140kit.com/datasets

Comment: both the URL now don't have any data set anymore

Answer (score 8):

Yes, there is. It's called the [Twitter API](http://dev.twitter.com/start).

Answer (score 3):

As we have access to limited tweets by Twitter-API, we should make use of third-party resellers like [Topsy](http://topsy.com/) for just the past data, [GNIP](http://gnip.com/) just for streaming data, or [DataSift](http://datasift.com/) for both streaming data as well as past data.

You might also want to check the following sites:
http://www.infochimps.com/collections/twitter-census
http://www.tweetarchivist.com/

Answer (score 2):

Twitter API allows provides partial results, it gives you the last 100 or even 500 tweets fo every search. If you need to keep tweets long term, twitter API shows its limits.
I had same need as you apparently hae and I developed a tool that queries twitter API periodically and stores search results on a Wordpress database.
I called the tools twittcorder and you can find a live demo on twittcorder.com
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

These other data sources are probably shared against the Twitter TOS. I wouldn't want to invest my time and effort building something on datasets that are non-repeatable. The Twitter Streaming API allows collection of a sample of Tweets.

Answer (score 0):

There's also Gnip: http://gnip.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Sysomos is there for complete data analysis including twitter, faecbook and various boards and forums