# How to map Twitter directed-graph/topology?

Tags: api, twitter, graph, topology

For my research, I want to use some data that can capture twitter users following each other . I want to represent this relationship in a big directed-graph. If you think about this graph it's probably very huge, I want to generate it and perhaps store it in adjacency-matrix format.

However when I tried to make use of Twitter's API, there are some useful methods like GET followers, GET friends I can use. But it has 150query/hour limit. At that rate, I would never finish crawling Twitter and generate a good enough direct-graph.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Just an implementation comment. For that huge data you need to use adjacency-list, because the matrix is sparse and huge! :)

Answer (score 1):

I remember that one of my friends contact this research group and they provide her a dataset.
http://twitter.mpi-sws.org/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to find a dataset instead. Try this SO question, the answers provide a few datasets of them.

[Twitter Data Archive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243125/twitter-data-archive)

Answer (score 0):

[Tribalytics-raw](http://tribalytics.com/tribalytics-raw) provides twitter followers and/or friends raw graph data as a service.

To comply with Twitter API's terms of service, only twitter users Ids are provided. You can extract the users metadata by yourself using twitter's `users/lookup` API endpoint, which is not so heavily rate-limited.

Full disclosure: I am the founder of this tool, and I have read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/limits-for-self-promotion-in-answers) before posting